# Не работает отладчик для компилятора MVSC в Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2015, qtcreator

Устанавливал VS 2015 community. Потом зашел в комплекты выбрал комплект MVSC 32 компилятора, для этого комплекта выбрал 1 из нескольких MVSC компиляторов, из отладчиков в списке отображается 3 штуки все для MIN GW. Я выбирал каждый из этих отладчиков, но результат на точке остановы прога в режиме отладки не останавливается + ? в комплекте компилятора при наведении на него:"`abi выбранного отладчика не соответствует abi инструментария` "
Помню я уже компилировал MVSC компилятором и отладчик работал
 В VS установил С++ при создании нового проекта, ибо там сперва ничего не было. Может мне еще что то установить надо, чтоб отладчик заработал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, не установлен CDB. (Это интерфейс отладчика командной строки от MS.)
Скачивать с microsoft.com в составе Windows SDK.
Подробности: http://datadump.ru/debugging-tools-for-windows/
см. также: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/

Возможно, в настройках Kit-а указан не тот отладчик.
Чтобы его настроить, идите в меню: Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits 
Выделить в списке нужный kit. В нижней части окна см. строку "debuger".

Comment: Да вы правы, у меня не был установлен debugger tools for Windows, Правда, я сам догадался, вот статья можно просветиться doc.crossplatform.ru/qtcreator/2.0.1/creator-debugger-engines.html